# To pull 1 record out of multiple records having same data in a field based on other fields

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

```
 A | B | C | D | E   
 a   y   6   12  21  
 b   n   3   10  5   
 c   n   4   12  12 
 c   n   7   12   2 
 c   y   1   12  22  
 d   n   6   10  32
 d   n   7   10  32
```

OUTPUT TABLE:

```
A | B | C | F 
a   y   6   21 
b   n   3   12 
c   y   1   22
d   n   6   10
```

I have a table that contains certain fields. From that table I want to remove duplicate records in A and produce the output table.

Now, the field F is calculated based on the field C when there are no duplicates for the records in A. So, if there is only one record of a in A then if C>5 then the F Column(Output table) pulls the record in E column. So, if record b has the value <5 in field C, then the F column (output table) will pull the record in D column for b. I have been able to achieve this using a case statement.

However, when there are duplicate records in column A, I want only one of the records based on the column B. Only that record should be pulled that has the value 'y' in column B and where the column F contains the value from column E. If none of the duplicate records in A have a value of 'n' in the B column, then pull any record with column D as column F in the output table. I am not able to figure out this part.

Please let me know if anything is not clear.

Code I am using:

```
SELECT A,B,C,
  CASE
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t1.A=t2.A)>1 
      THEN (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN b='y' THEN E ELSE D END
            FROM MyTable t3
            WHERE t3.A=t1.A
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN b='y' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
    ELSE {

case when cast(C  as float) >= 5.00  then (Case when E = '0.00' then D else E end) 
     when  cast(C  as float)< 5.00   then D end )


}
  END AS F
FROM MyTable t1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to encapsulate this logic in a Function to make it look cleaner, but the logic would go like this:

IF the record count of rows in the table with the same value for `A` as the current row is greater than 1, THEN SELECT the TOP 1 record with this value for `A` ORDER BY `CASE WHEN b='y' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`

Use another `CASE WHEN b='y'` to determine if you will use column `E` or `D` for output column `F`.

And ELSE (the record count is not greater than 1), use your existing CASE expression.

EDIT:   Here is a more psuedo-codey explanation:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT A,B,C,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A, ORDER BY CASE WHEN b='y' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) rn
FROM MyTable
)
 SELECT A,B,C,
  CASE
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t1.A=t2.A)>1 
      THEN CASE WHEN b='y' THEN E ELSE D END
    ELSE {use your existing CASE Expression}
  END AS F
FROM cte t1
WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand by this - 'IF the record count of rows in the table with the same value for A as the current row is greater than 1, THEN SELECT the TOP 1 record with this value for A ORDER BY CASE WHEN b='y' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END' Can you explain.

Comment: It still shows the same number of record and the the F column shows the value for the first record of A. Not their specific values. It is because of the TOP 1

Comment: Ok, yes some logic has to be applied to the outer query to limit to only one row per distinct value for A.  You can use a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()` expression to get this.   Not sure what you mean about the F column showing the first value.   If you used the `ORDER BY` I gave, it will give your desired results.

Comment: No that issue has been resolved. only I am not able to obtain the one row for those values.